# Weird behavior of 'diag' function

Tags: r, matrix

Can someone explain why

```
> diag(1)

#     [,1]
#[1,]    1
```

or

```
> diag(c(-1,1))

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   -1    0
#[2,]    0    1
```

but

```
> diag(-1)
```

> Error in diag(-1) : invalid 'nrow' value (< 0)

Comment: `diag(-1, nrow = 1)`?

Comment: You asked this same question [several days ago](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2018-September/076802.html) on r-devel and received numerous excellent responses. I wouldn't expect a different or more authoritative answer here.

Comment: I did indeed ask the same question but never saw any answers.  My apologies for reposting.  The answer given here was very clear.

Answer (score 2):

From `?diag`:

```
Usage:

     diag(x = 1, nrow, ncol)

Details:

     ‘diag’ has four distinct usages:

       1. ‘x’ is a matrix, when it extracts the diagonal.

       2. ‘x’ is missing and ‘nrow’ is specified, it returns an
          identity matrix.

       3. ‘x’ is a scalar (length-one vector) and the only argument, it
          returns a square identity matrix of size given by the scalar.

       4. ‘x’ is a ‘numeric’ (‘complex’, ‘numeric’, ‘integer’,
          ‘logical’, or ‘raw’) vector, either of length at least 2 or
          there were further arguments.  This returns a matrix with the
          given diagonal and zero off-diagonal entries.
```

Usage 1 and 4 are the most unambiguous, but usage 2 and 3 should be better explained.

It helps understanding if we think about generating a [scalar matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix#Scalar_matrix) with function `diag`. `x` is the scalar on the main diagonal and `nrow` is the dimension of the matrix.

```
diag(2, 3)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    0    0
#[2,]    0    2    0
#[3,]    0    0    2

diag(-1, 2)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   -1    0
#[2,]    0   -1
```

An identity matrix is a special case of a scalar matrix with `x = 1`.

```
diag(1, 3)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    0
#[2,]    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    0    1

diag(1, 0)
#<0 x 0 matrix>
```

**This two-argument specification is the recommended way for generating an identity matrix**. But there is a frequently used single-argument shortcut:

```
diag(3)
diag(0)
```

In this fashion the scalar value must be non-negative, as it is interpreted as matrix dimension.

Answer (score 2):

From `?diag`:

> Using diag(x) can have unexpected effects if x is a vector that could be of length one.
>
> Use diag(x, nrow = length(x)) for consistent behaviour.

Then you might want to use it as follows:

```
diag(-1, nrow = 1)

#     [,1]
#[1,]   -1
```